# train_test_split() error: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sampling

Fairly new to Python but building out my first RF model based on some classification data. I've converted all of the labels into int64 numerical data and loaded into X and Y as a numpy array, but I am hitting an error when I am trying to train the models.

Here is what my arrays look like:

```
>>> X = np.array([[df.tran_cityname, df.tran_signupos, df.tran_signupchannel, df.tran_vmake, df.tran_vmodel, df.tran_vyear]])

>>> Y = np.array(df['completed_trip_status'].values.tolist())

>>> X
array([[[   1,    1,    2,    3,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    3,    1,
            3,    1,    1,    1,    1,    2,    1,    3,    1,    3,    3,
            2,    3,    3,    1,    1,    1,    1],
        [   0,    5,    5,    1,    1,    1,    2,    2,    0,    2,    2,
            3,    1,    2,    5,    5,    2,    1,    2,    2,    2,    2,
            2,    4,    3,    5,    1,    0,    1],
        [   2,    2,    1,    3,    3,    3,    2,    3,    3,    2,    3,
            2,    3,    2,    2,    3,    2,    2,    1,    1,    2,    1,
            2,    2,    1,    2,    3,    1,    1],
        [   0,    0,    0,   42,   17,    8,   42,    0,    0,    0,   22,
            0,   22,    0,    0,   42,    0,    0,    0,    0,   11,    0,
            0,    0,    0,    0,   28,   17,   18],
        [   0,    0,    0,   70,  291,   88,  234,    0,    0,    0,  222,
            0,  222,    0,    0,  234,    0,    0,    0,    0,   89,    0,
            0,    0,    0,    0,   40,  291,  131],
        [   0,    0,    0, 2016, 2016, 2006, 2014,    0,    0,    0, 2015,
            0, 2015,    0,    0, 2015,    0,    0,    0,    0, 2015,    0,
            0,    0,    0,    0, 2016, 2016, 2010]]])

>>> Y
array(['NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO',
       'NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO',
       'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO'], 
      dtype='|S3')

>>> X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line
> ```
>
> 2039, in train_test_split
>           arrays = indexable(*arrays)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line
>   206, in indexable
>           check_consistent_length(*result)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line
>   181, in check_consistent_length
>           " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
>
> ```
> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 29]
> ```

Comment: In the future, please post **programming questions** to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). This Q&A is about data science, not programming.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You are running into that error because your `X` and `Y` don't have the same length (which is what `train_test_split` requires), i.e., `X.shape[0] != Y.shape[0]`. Given your current code:

```
>>> X.shape
(1, 6, 29)
>>> Y.shape
(29,)
```

To fix this error:

1. Remove the extra list from inside of `np.array()` when defining `X` or remove the extra dimension afterwards with the following command: `X = X.reshape(X.shape[1:])`. Now, the shape of `X` will be (6, 29).
2. Transpose `X` by running `X = X.transpose()` to get equal number of samples in `X` and `Y`. Now, the shape of `X` will be (29, 6) and the shape of `Y` will be (29,).

Comment: Amazing this worked for me! Thanks Tuomastik! I really appreciate the guidance :)

Answer (score 3):

Isn't train_test_split expecting both `X` and `Y` to be a list of same length? Your X has length of 6 and Y has length of 29. May be try converting that to pandas dataframe (with 29x6 dimension) and try again?

Given your data, it looks like you have 6 features. In that case, try to convert your `X` to have 29 rows and 6 columns. Then pass that dataframe to `train_test_split`. You can convert your list to dataframe using `pd.DataFrame.from_records`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sal! You're right, I just had to convert it to the same lengths. My X.shape was (1, 6, 29) and Y.shape was (29, ). I just had to reshape them and it all worked fine for me :)